# How do you combine a multiple condition

Tags: jquery

I have a JQUERY condition and it works fine but I would just like to combine it. Basically if Date id or Name id is blank display none.

```
if( !$.trim( $('#name').html() ).length ) {
    $("#lastUpdate").css('display', 'none');
}
if( !$.trim( $('#date').html() ).length ) {
    $("#lastUpdate").css('display', 'none');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a job for an 'or' statement:

```
if( !$.trim( $('#name').html() ).length || !$.trim( $('#date').html() ).length ) {
    $("#lastUpdate").css('display', 'none');
}
```

Although you can probably eliminate the `.length` part, since empty strings evaluate to `false` when converted to Boolean:

```
if ( !$.trim( $('#name').html() ) || !$.trim( $('#date').html() ) ) {
    $("#lastUpdate").css('display', 'none');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `||` it means `or` :

```
if( !$.trim( $('#name').html() ).length ||  !$.trim( $('#date').html() ) ) {
    $("#lastUpdate").css('display', 'none');
    }
```

### Logical Operators

Logical operators are used to determine the logic between variables or values.

Given that `x=6` and `y=3`, the table below explains the logical operators:

```
Operator    Description          Example
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
&&             and          (x < 10 && y > 1) is true
||             or           (x==5 || y==5) is false
!              not          !(x==y) is true
```

Comment: This is great. Also if || represents or what represents "And"?

Comment: Ooops Sorry. I missed your comment I see its &&